# Volumetric Lighting/Light Shafts in DirectX

Tags: c++, directx, hlsl, lighting

So currently I am trying to implement Light Shafts into my DirectX Engine. I read the Nvidia GPU Gems Article (https://developer.nvidia.com/gpugems/gpugems3/part-ii-light-and-shadows/chapter-13-volumetric-light-scattering-post-process) I am new to Graphics Programming so could someone explain this in a much more dumbed down version? At this stage based on the article linked above I need to calculate a  vector from pixel to light source in screen space and display a texture with those coordinates from the Vector?

Comment: The concepts presented in GPU gems are very advanced ones. They can't be easily dumbed down without information loss.

Comment: When I say dumbed down I mean to say if someone could explain step by step of what I need to do, how it's done and what the code presented in the article does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This technique consists of three main steps.

1.) Render your light source only, but occluded by the scene geometry to a black texture. This could be done by rendering the light source against the scene's depth-stencil buffer and performing depth-tests or stencil tests to only keep visibe pixels of the light source.

2.) You need to perform a radial blur with the light source's center as the blur center point.

3.) Finally, you additively blend the result with your scene like you would with bloom.